# Creating a dictionary from two lists with repeated keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists

```
subject_id = [10030, 10030, 10250, 10510]
student_id = [55000, 55804, 55804, 55000]
```

I would like to create a dictionary with subject_id as the key and student_id as value.
When I try `dict`, `zip` because of the repeated key value, I only get the second value and not the first.

```
result = {10030: 55804, 10250: 55804, 10510: 55000}
```

My thought is to have the value be a list. So when the repeated key comes up, the corresponding student_id is added as a new element to the list.

Desired result :

```
my_dict = {10030: [55000, 55804], 10250: [55804], 10510: [55000]}
```

How can this be done?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `defaultdict(list)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

subject_id = [10030, 10030, 10250, 10510]
student_id = [55000, 55804, 55804, 55000]

result = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in zip(subject_id, student_id):
   result[a].append(b)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the simplest answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

Without collections, you'll have to iterate and test:

```
subject_id = [10030, 10030, 10250, 10510]
student_id = [55000, 55804, 55804, 55000]

ssd = {}
for i in range(len(subject_id)):
    if subject_id[i] not in ssd:
        ssd[subject_id[i]] = student_id[i]
    else:
        ssd[subject_id[i]] = [ssd[subject_id[i]], student_id[i]]
```

Comment: The result from this solution slightly deviates from the OP's desired result: not all dictionary values are lists.

Comment: Thanks @Xukrao My original answer was list-only output and for some reason I got it in my head that it wasn't desired. I have rolled-back to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. The idea is to count the number of copies of each element in `subject_id` and index the `student_id` list accordingly:

```
import collections

subject_id = [10030, 10030, 10250, 10510]
student_id = [55000, 55804, 55804, 55000]
 
solution = {}
cumsum = 0
for item, count in collections.Counter(subject_id).items():
    solution[item] = student_id[cumsum:cumsum+count]
    cumsum += count
print(solution)
```